# Why does it seem so hard to accumulate upvotes on Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, upvotes

I swear I don't mean this to complain or anything. I am just wondering if it's some kind of community standard.

Typically if I see a question I find helpful or interesting, I'll upvote it. However in general this does not seem to be what people do. It seems a huge majority of questions have less than three upvotes, even ones that have been viewed thousands of times and contain insightful answers and discussion.

Even the "hot questions" that come up on the homepage are often only at 0-1. It seems like this is particuarly annoying to new users, since the site barely has any functionality beyond looking and posting at first, and the main way to get reputation at an early stage is upvotes on your questions.

Meanwhile, I have a few questions on other Stack Exchange sites, and even though the communities are typical much smaller than Stack Overflow, they easily get a bunch of upvotes. On Stack Overflow, on the other hand, even questions I post with hundreds or thousands of views and several good answers usually sit at 0-1. It's not like it costs anything to upvote (like it does to downvote), so why do users seem so stingy with upvotes? I'm just curious if it's some sort of rule in the Stack Overflow community I'm missing.

Comment: @thnkwthprtls known "issue", the related sidebar is awesome, better than any search or the initial question search. Probably because it's also taking into account tags.

Comment: Now that I think about it the sidebar is almost always better with results lol. Thanks for the tip :)

Comment: Users can view a question if they are not signed in, but they cannot vote for the question. This is one factor in the view-upvote disparity.

Comment: Dilution, mainly.  So many questions, so few good ones, so much stuff to weed through.  Upvotes on questions mainly occur when someone else is looking for the same answer and finds your question, well written and with some good answers (or at least hints at an answer).  I will occasionally give an upvote for an exceptionally well-written question, though -- clearly asks the right question, includes relevant code, error messages, input, output, etc.  This is so rare that I'd upvote 2-3 times if I could.

Comment: Why do you even want votes? I'm here for the answers. To me the only purpose for votes is to have the best answers rise to the surface. Personal rep re: votes is almost beside the point.

Comment: @rism Mostly just because upvotes = reputation, and there's so many things pertaining to what you are able to do on the site that are tied to that.

Comment: I think it's mostly because people are more interested in answers than questions.

Comment: Related: [Why aren't people voting for questions?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/9508/262755) | [Why aren't people voting as much as they used to?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/74271/262755)  | [Why are votes per post on the decrease (what can we do to improve this)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80312/262755)

Comment: And appreciating a good question is not for everybody.

Comment: @rism Because for a new user, getting the privilege to ask for question clarification through five answer upvotes shouldn't be harder than doing so by getting 25 suggested edits accepted.

Comment: The hot questions are by definition having much activity in relation to their age and views, that normally happens for new questions, because being new they have low views and thus not many people could upvote them.

Comment: That is so true. I recently found a bug in two of the assemblers although the bug was not severe at all but man its a bug. And i got 2 upvotes while 29 people saw it.

Comment: @HotLicks *"This is so rare that I'd upvote 2-3 times if I could."* you and [me](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/366192/849891) both. but apparently we're abysmally in minority. or in abysmal minority. or both.

Comment: probably one of the best questions on stackoverflow

Answer (score 125, accepted):

Personally, I will upvote anything that is helpful or interesting, but I am careful not to upvote incorrect information.

Many questions are too specific to the asker's situation, and therefore not interesting to me.

Answers on topics I don't know about could be wrong, so either I have to take time to verify the information, or just skip it.

Questions/answers with a lot of upvotes tend to be ones that Google brings viewers to, because they are useful for a large audience.  For example, my top voted answer is about a specific error message which someone would find if they had that same error message.

Comment: That's a really good point about Google, I hadn't really thought about that

Comment: The best way to write a question is not to ask "what should I do in my program" but to ask "what should be done in any program with this issue?"  Nobody searches Google to find answers to *your* problems.

Comment: Nobody except your boss, perhaps.  :)

Comment: This is very interesting since from the perspective of asking a question the pressure is on being specific.  However I must admit that too large a proportion of my up votes come from Googling.

Comment: My upvoting is directly related to my desperation level. If I google something and find it straightaway, upvoting won't even cross my mind. If I've been researching something for hours and then finally find the perfect little answer, say, on using XNOR for comparison (thank you @Ignacio-Vazquez-Abrams) my overflowing gratitude needs to find expression and I upvote. My own top-voted answer is the one I'm the least proud of, simply straight out of Apple docs. Curiously, a few month ago, I found myself googling it and deciding to upvote. Only after I logged in, I realized it was my own answer.

Comment: Stackoverflow questions in 2009 be like: "What's a CSS?"   *gets 1000 upvotes *

Answer (score 99):

+1, *if I could*... but I need 15 rep to do so.  This is perhaps an appropriate introduction to my point.

I'm "new here", so I apologize if I'm speaking out of turn.  However the fact that I'm so "new here" (in the contribution sense) is exactly why I'm interested in this topic.  This is an attempt to describe my perspective on the up-vote issue from the "new contributor" lens.

I have been a "passive" (not-logged-in) user for some time (years), and have derived enormous benefit from this site.  (THANKS!)  When I first learned how fantastic this site was, I immediately started to try to upvote everything in sight.  Of course, not being a logged-in user, I couldn't upvote.  So then I signed up for an account so that I could upvote stuff (a threshold already too high for many!).  But even *with a login*, you need rep to upvote -- for very justifiable reasons.

I don't know what fraction of logged-in users don't have enough rep to upvote, but I think this is part of the acculturation (initiation?) process of this site.  **Is there perhaps a learned *dis-*incentive to upvote, once you've got enough rep to upvote?**  Or, phrased another way, **how to incentivize up-voting**?  Is that a even a good idea, or is it a terrible idea that misses the point?

Stuff like the [six simple rules for increasing rep](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast) is a provocative (productive? cynical?) discussion that touches on game theory of the (unfortunate? helpful?) competitive aspects of rep on StackExchange, and the tradeoffs in up-voting (*and* down-voting).  From a pure game-theory perspective, the ideal case is to for *you* to up-vote *nothing*, and for *everyone else* to up-vote *your* stuff... right?

So my perspective, being a long-time "lurker" and now wanting to be a "contributor" (in the sense of the [internet culture 1-percent rule](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1%25_rule_(Internet_culture))), I need up-votes to actually productively contribute to the site.  After finally deciding to become more "active" in the culture, it requires significant time and effort to do so (I also posted a question about [how newbies should start](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252149/how-does-a-new-user-get-started-on-stackoverflow); full disclosure, this is my question).  I'm also wishing/hoping that people are willing to up-vote enthusiastic and genuine contributions, especially from newbs to get us over the initial contribution "hump", and hope that I'll do the same once I have enough rep to do so! ... without going so far as to encourage swill questions or allow spam and other cruft.  A tricky balance, no doubt.

Anyway, just newb's too-lengthy, pie-eyed, rosy (naive?) view of the beauty of SE.  It's great to be here. :)

Comment: +1 - and welcome to the active side of the community.

Comment: *`I don't know what fraction of logged-in users don't have enough rep to upvote,`* - there seem to be around `771316` users with rep less than 15 out of `3103258` users, that's about ~25%

Comment: I would have given out a lot more upvotes for questions that directly helped me out if I had had the ability. Fortunately I did get a "Was this answer helpful?" prompt beneath some of the response. I always dutifully clicked, but I honestly don't have any idea if that was useful feedback for the site or not.

Comment: @ouflak I'm not sure if it has an effect or not, but it shows up somewhere (I think).

Comment: Wow! I've really enjoyed reading your answer. Thanks :-) And +1 of course

Comment: Based on this post, I hope you continue to post more and only lurk less. +1

Comment: I don't think there's much of a learned dis-incentive to upvote.  Probably like a lot of users who have been around here a while, I have a much lower (mental) threshold for upvoting low-rep users.  I really `want` them to have a positive experience.  It's just that new users rarely post interesting, researched questions.  Most new-user questions are extremely basic sql/javascript/regex (or just off topic entirely).

Answer (score 71):

Is the question:

*Why is it so hard to get upvotes?*

or:

*Why hasn't anything I've answered received upvotes?*

I don't believe the first question is what you are asking so I will address the second. I believe this is because high upvote questions come from many addresses but two in particular:

### The intersection of *Old* and *Good*

I have been answering questions on here for over 3 years. I have 200+ answers only 4 of which have netted more than 10 upvotes. The real craziness is that these aren't even my best answers. I would be willing to bet that if I took a personal inventory and ranked all my answers top to bottom(by my own subjective interpretation of good) it would be the mirror image of my answers ordered chronologically.

This is because my best answers are the questions I have answered recently. This came after 3 years of trial and error. Having **High-Rep** users scowl at me. Trawling the front page and answering everything that popped up. Learning how to use the formatting tools. Most of these answers have 0 upvotes!

This is compared to my old answers that have just been sitting there harvesting upvotes for 3 years. Now like a good citizen I have gone back and tidied them up, but there isn't anything special about them. Their upvotes came from statisical collisions with folks that had that problem, that day, and felt inclined to award me an upvote. As the answer started to get traction it started to show up in more searches.

I think the best cases to demonstrate this lie within the profiles of **long-term**, non [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/users/22656/jon-skeet) type members. People with rep in the 10-20K range. These folks typically have a few 100+ upvote answers under their belt that are not the result of serial upvoting. I would hypothesize that a lot of those answers are a combination of good and old.

### The intersection of *Hot Topic* and *You are the expert*

A lot of the highest-rep user's gained much of their rep from answering a *Low Hanging Fruit*. During the Stack Overflow *Big Bang* these existed in abundance, but dissipated quickly. Many of the 100K+ rep users got a lot of their reputation from answering these proto-state questions. Nowadays pretty much the only analog to these circumstances occurs when a new lib comes out. Some users are bound to be early adopters or creators of that library. If that library later blows up in a big way and say becomes an industry standard a la `jQuery` those answers will help lots of people. Many of these folks will award upvotes. The SO users whose rep will benefit are the individuals that invested early.

### Summary

You've only been answering for 9 months. Stick with it. Answer lots of questions well and in time you will reap compounding returns in terms of upvotes. Remember that reputation on this site is not necessarily an indicator of competence. It could come from answering *12,000* questions adequately, answering 1 question well 5 years ago, or just getting plain old lucky.

Comment: One of the best answers i've ever read on this site. great job

Comment: Speaking of "old and good" I got an upvote just yesterday on an answer I made 2 years ago (almost to the day). It's not a *highly* up-voted topic (the question has +5) but it's apparently something that someone tried to find the answer to. (My highest rated post on SO? +27 on a question about "wtf is this?" and "this" was regex. My highest rated question is only +1...Elsewhere on the network...my highest answer is to "Solid material made from human blood?" over on Worldbuilding; highest question? "How do I create a very long delay with Redstone?" on Arcade--another old one)

Answer (score 39):

I would add that SO - and SE - tends to not upvote questions nearly as much as we ought.  I try to make it a rule that if a question is interesting enough to answer, it's worth an upvote; I shouldn't be answering bad questions, after all.  I think the community would be better off if questions were upvoted more - good questions - because it would encourage good askers to come back, and discourage bad askers.

Comment: My general rule of thumb is that if I could answer the question and somebody else got there first with either the same answer or a better one, I upvote that.  If I see a newbie posting a terrible question but genuinely showing effort, such as editing their post to include stuff they should have had there to begin with, I give them an upvote solely based on their willingness to improve and leave a comment letting them know what they did right. And, of course, any time I use the site for it's intended 'library' purpose, I give an upvote to questions and/or answers that state or solve my problem.

Answer (score 10):

> *It seems a huge majority of questions have < 3 upvotes, even ones that have been viewed thousands of times and contain insightful answers and discussion.*

I personally think that the main reason behind the difference between number of **Views** and number of **Upvotes** on Stack Overflow is because most of the pages hits on Stack Overflow are because of ***Google***.

Let's imagine a situation when a programmer/student has a **problem**:

`->` He/She *(obviously, as we all do)* **googles it.**

`->` 99% chance it is already discussed on **Stack Overflow**.

`->` finds the solution and gets **back to work**. `:P`

Now **most** of such kind of users are likely the beginners and so are not supposed to be registered on Stack Overflow. **Even I; as I think most of us; registered on Stack Overflow after using it like for at least a couple of months.** *(almost an year in my case).* `:P`

Then I decided to contribute and give it back from what I learnt this duration.

And also the fact Stack Overflow has the most number of page hits than any other Stack Exchange site:
[image: Traffic on Stack Overflow]
**Source:** https://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic

You can clearly see that Stack Overflow has more number of page hits per day than the total number of registered and unregistered users.

So in my opinion ***we clearly can't expect a particular number of Upvotes on a post as the number of views for the same.***

Comment: *`It seems a huge majority of questions have < 3 upvotes, `* - it seems that 3750938 out of 19987615 questions have 3 or more upvotes, which makes 16236677 with less than 3 votes. that's about 19% to 81% ratio

Answer (score 8):

I don't have statistic data to support my suspicions, but I suppose, it's just because Stack Overflow has too many questions to simply read the big part of them even if someone is very boring.

I've noticed smaller sites are highly upvoting. It's possible to read all new questions every day, or at least all questions from given 'category' (region, a type of travel, etc.) and it doesn't take long. There are many active users upvoting everything they find good.

On Stack Overflow, it's possible to see only a tiny fraction of the whole mass of questions, in the same time most of them are very specific, so even if I'm a Java specialist, *almost all* questions in [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) are for me of limited, if not none, usability (and answers, consequently, the same).

It's much easier to get more reputation on the other sites with the same expertise level and the same number of questions. On the other side, on Stack Overflow is much easier to post **a lot of** answers because there are so many questions.

It means, to accumulate many upvotes on Stack Overflow, you need an immense number of answers.

Comment: I don't agree with this I think it's more a behavioural thing. A lot of users want to just get answers to a problem and not bother upvoting anything they find useful because ... well ... they don't really care. 

I don't have a lot of points but I have questions with 100s of views without a single upvote. People just don't like up-voting questions...