# How can a mediocre programmer build expertise and reputation points on Stack Overflow when it is rare to find unanswered basic questions?

Tags: discussion

How can a programmer of average ability (mediocre) build expertise and reputation points on Stack Overflow when it is rare to find unanswered basic questions?

Comment: If you're a mediocre developer then you should focus on mediocre (and harder) questions, not basic ones; confirming what you already know won't help you very much. It's like any other way of learning: aim higher than your current position and you'll get better. Go through a language specification to answer something in depth or write up a detailed answer that draws from several sources; you'll always learn something.

Comment: If you have a really good question you can pose it and maybe even answer it too. You don't need to answer question of others all the time.

Comment: Possibly helpful, if there is an active chat room for your languages of choice, go there and lurk. Participate a little once you learn the culture. I can honestly say that hanging out in the PHP room, paying attention, and following along on what they talk about there has advanced my skills noticeably. In the javascript room, they talk about poop a lot, but there's nuggets (scat puns!) of information to pick up too.

Comment: You won't truly benefit from answering questions on [main] until you **actually build expertise** in something. See also [How does a new user get started on Stack Overflow?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/252149/456814).

Comment: Related?: [Why does it seem so hard to accumulate upvotes in SO?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251084/456814).

Comment: i'd say do not answer if unless you are an expert at something and absolutely confident your answer is correct.

Comment: That actually is what the reputation is about. This is not just another game where it should be equally easy for everyone to collect coins. People with high reputation should be that way, because they have shown their expertise on SO. People with low rep, because they haven't. If you don't have anything to show, exactly that is what should be reflected in your reputation. Build up expertise, show it to others, then you will get reputation. Its a bit like that thing called "real life".

Comment: Why would you want to "build reputation on SO?"  Also, it's **simply not** rare to find questions **that match your ability**.  So basically "shut up and go answer some questions" :)

Comment: If you're after expertise, you will want to camp out on the "Unanswered" tab and look for the difficult questions that others haven't been able to answer. You will have to devote a considerable amount of time to figuring out the answer, but it's a worthwhile investment, not only for your rep, but also for your growth as a programmer. Picking the low-hanging fruit gets tiring after you get about 1k or 2k under your belt and have basic privileges. It is also intellectually stunting.

Comment: Almost all questions are of the kind that a mediocre programmer can answer. What's hard is finding questions that are worth your time when you've left mediocrity behind.

Comment: Why restricting yourself to *unanswered* questions? Occasionally you can make a better answer than those present, and get your share of points.

Comment: @Cupcake You *can* benefit by answering questions. I learnt quite a lot in topics I am not an expert in. It may be harder and take more time to write an answer, but it also teaches you by looking at real world problems.

Comment: I think some of the commenters are forgetting the fact that most questions have answers in a matter of minutes, so a "mediocre" cannot step in and compete with other posters for the upvotes.  By the time the "mediocre" programmer has the answer, everyone has already moved on and no one is going to look at your answer.  Now, I do like the philosophy of tackle a hard question and don't worry about getting upvoted.  Just see if you can come up with a good answer to the question and then check your answers against the answers others gave.  Expertise first, reputation (much) later.

Comment: @JoeBlow Certain level of reputation is needed to use SO effectively. To play devils advocate, someone could even go as far as to say, to use SO effectively, one needs so much reputation, that they can afford to give 500 point bounties. So anybody under a few thousand rep points has a practical reason to "build reputation on SO".

Comment: @hyde .. I'm not sure I agree buddy.  I often asks questions (about engineering or whatever) on forums where I am utterly new and have no profile etc.  If it's a reasonable question people answer it.  The only way to deal with the "crap flow" is for mods to delete crap questions, but it's not going to happen. Some thoughts on the matter .. http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/252967/294884

Comment: What is mediocre actually? We all started somewhere and no one called us mediocre.

We need to build the knowledge first hand. If we are late , we are late.

It is not a game where you have to be the quickest, the strongest.

Once you feel ready, go / do , otherwise go slow. Don't burden yourself with over expectation.

"Rome was not built in a single day"

Comment: There is this movie that I found great, groundhog day.

Comment: @AndyK http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Groundhog_Day_(film)

Comment: @likejiujitsu : Indeed, start all over again until you get better and better

Comment: Hmm, how can I get high marks in an exam, if I don't know the course material?  The whole point of reputation points in Stack Overflow is that mediocre programmers aren't supposed to have them.

Comment: Browse the `/Unanswered` page, sorted by newest, and filtered for a tag you're interested in (http://stackoverflow.com/unanswered/tagged/?tab=newest). It's the best way to find mediocre answerable questions :)

Comment: This came to my mind "How can a mediocre programmer build expertise and reputation on his/her office when it is hard to find basic tasks?"

Comment: Answer easy questions without regard to their quality? You'll get far more upvotes for answering a duplicate question about a basic language feature than helping someone with a tricky build problem.

Comment: It's easy; just stop being a mediocre programmer!  Seriously, why would anyone want to  accept anything less than expert advice?

Comment: the title should be *Why* can a mediocre programmer build expertise and reputation points on Stack Overflow when it is rare to find unanswered basic questions?

Comment: Learn from difficult questions if you cannot answer them. Harvest questions and try answering a few each day. As for me, many of my answer, some quite good, have gone unrewarded. My country will execute me if I not get enough points.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

## Idea Number One:

You must ignore the points.  From the [StackOverflow blog](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2013/09/five-years-ago-stack-overflow-launched-then-a-miracle-occurred/):

> It was a gamble: would people really take time out of their busy lives to answer other people’s questions, for nothing more than fake internet points and bragging rights?
>
> **It turns out that people will do anything for fake internet points.**

First and foremost, keep in mind that they *really are fake internet points*.  Don't get caught up in the prison-for-the-mind of the "SE Matrix".  It's a pyramid scheme--early adopters have high scores from before the floods...when people thought voting was fun.  Now it's "oh, answer, kthxbye" plus any basic question is closed as duplicate (pointing the upvote power to someone who was on earlier).

I don't envy whoever's job it is to manage the growth and balance here as a "points economist".  They use secret algorithms to catch serial downvoting or other gamings of the system, and occasionally a Deux Ex Machina of admins locating people who are purposely ruining it for everyone.

*(Among people I know, one was an editor for the last edition of the D&D books.  He sat around with spreadsheets all day trying to make it "more fun" by eliminating exploits and improving the overall balance.  I'd sooner poke my eyeballs out with a...fork.  He enjoyed it because he's a Magic-the-Gathering-Tournament master and loves numbers.  To me it's the worst job ever.)*

## Idea Number Two:

Don't shoot for the "easy questions".  If you have time to kill, attack a weird one...something you have no clue about, but has zero answers.  It's not hard to set up a virtual machine these days, why not give it a shot?  Pretend it's something you have to do for work and there's a non-fake-Internet-point payoff (if that helps).

I do this from time to time when I'm bored.  For instance:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7411411/211160

Note 9 upvotes on the comment *"Fun fact: I learned Lua tonight just to solve this unanswered question. :) "*

Or what about Smalltalk?  I'd never used it, but had been interested...

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2082999/211160

If someone called me a mediocre programmer I'd probably challenge them to some kind of duel.  *(Unfortunately our society has done away with the whole "fighting for honor until the dishonorable person is killed" thing.)*  But I certainly don't think either of those questions represent any madskillz other than being doggedly determined to make the stupid thing work.  If I can do these tasks in a few hours, a "mediocre" programmer could do it just with persistence.  And likely learn more than I did (I think I get dumber each time I do one).

Mediocre may be where you're at, but it's not where you have to stay.  Remember: ["You don't have to be a genious to use a computer."](http://blog.hostilefork.com/osborne-one-basic-fun-history/)

Comment: +1 If you want to participate effectively in the community, IMO your goal should be to help people, not to build points. There is also no necessity to building points.  You can benefit from the community without points, and maybe one day when you are more experienced contribute more effectively.

Comment: Modern concept of money is not real either. Take BitCoin, for example. And yet everybody is so crazy about it.

Comment: @Neolisk There is an interesting angle that if BitCoin is battle-tested, and proven, then we could each print our own currency.  It's not about the value of "a bitcoin" but a decentralized system that replaces the stock market.  It's like being able to start your own website instead of being forced to publish on blogger.  We trust StackExchange, but why?  [Declare indepedence.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pXVlQTC2yB0)  Just a matter of time, I think...

Comment: @HostileFork lol at idea one, +1 albeit its been two years already

Answer (score 124):

A programmer of average ability (mediocre) can build expertise and reputation on Stack Overflow by several means:

### Aim a little higher

As Jeroen Vannevel stated in his comment - you should be looking for something other than *just* the basic questions. Just like it's hard to swim the 5k when you restrict yourself to splashing in the kiddy pool, it's hard to build expertise when you restrict yourself to the "basic" questions.

Go find some more challenging questions - especially if it's something that will push you a little further.

### Look for new grounds

When most people ask questions like this, it's usually because they're looking around in a very current/popular tag. It's what they're learning (or just recently learned) in university, it's the current "thing" in the business where they work, etc.

There's new stuff being developed, new areas to ask/answer all the time - even more so in tech. Go find one of those niche areas and set up early. Sure, you may not be all that familiar yourself - see the first part: Aim higher, challenge yourself.

### It's not just the answers

Lots of people get so focused on the answers that they forget that truly good questions are solid gold - see if there's some empty space for a quality "canonical" question. Quality questions will also generate rep, and if it's an area you're not totally familiar with, you learn some more yourself. Win-win.

Be careful with this one - do check for duplicates, do follow all the good question-asking guidance, etc.

Comment: "it's hard to build expertise when you restrict yourself to the "basic" questions." Actually, often it's the reverse. You can amass ridicolous amounts of rep by "winning the lottery" of basic questions. When an answer starts to float on top, many who entered to answer (because it's an easy question) will upvote it; then the "passive upvotes" from Google searches may kick in if the argument is popular ([example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/351409/214671)). Difficult/niche questions, instead, often get only the upvotes of other specialists in the subject, no matter how well researched they are.

Comment: @MatteoItalia he's talking about actual programming expertise and skill there, not stack overflow reputation score.

Comment: Also, as for "winning the lottery" and amassing a ton of reputation with stupid but popular questions: that was something you could only do in 2008 when there were basic questions left to ask and/or answer :)

Comment: @Mahn I disagree. [I "won the lottery" in 2012](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11969014/142637) OK, nowhere near 1000 upvotes, but still ridiculous :-)

Comment: @MatteoItalia - the question asked about both rep and *expertise*. The part of the answer you cited is dealing with the latter, not the former. What I should probably add to the answer is that as you build expertise, it becomes easier to build rep through means other than just "winning the lottery". (e.g.: the harder bounty questions)

Comment: Don't be afraid to give an answer that *may* turn out to be "bad" -- i.e., gets shot down and downvoted *immediately*. It will at the very least tell *you* what you still need to learn. Leaving your answer, instead of immediately deleting it, may also help others (if the comments against are clearly expressing *why* it is not a good answer).

Comment: @MatteoItalia: but like the lottery, it does not happen often. I won the lottery once (`to_string`), with close to 2,500 answers; and I am not sure the question qualifies as basic since it involved a new version of the Standard that had not been released yet.

Comment: I've built an awful lot of expertise by asking questions. Often they go unanswered, so I keep banging my head against them until I answer them myself. Sometimes my answers get upvoted and I get a few reputation points out of it, but I ALWAYS feel like a superstar when I answer a question that no one else on SO has answered for me after a few days.

Answer (score 54):

*If* you're looking to improve yourself you're looking at this completely the wrong way. Like [vascowhite](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254903/458741) I'm mainly self-taught in the primary language I know and completely self-taught in the other languages I use. I've also had no training and I don't have a computer science degree. What you're missing, and what I think vascowhite's answer's missing is that *nothing* has taught me more than Stack Overflow and due to that there's no need to settle for mediocrity.

Your question is how does a mediocre programmer build expertise. My answer is slightly different... you're only a mediocre programmer because you choose to pigeon-hole yourself that way. Rather than determining to be average and gain reputation concentrate on how you can learn to be better than average and the reputation will come naturally. In order to get reputation you need 2 things:

1. The ability to write posts that succinctly explain or solve a problem including both code and an English explanation. In other words, you need to be able to explain technical concepts well.
2. Knowledge of the subject you're posting on.

Neither of these are things you can magically conjure out of the air, but if I have one bit of advice for someone who honestly wants to learn something here it's: answer everything. I do *not* mean click "Post Your Answer". I mean attempt to answer everything within a problem domain that you have some experience.

As you post check everyone else's answer and assess it against your understanding of the question. If you're completely wrong then it doesn't matter and you don't need to post. If you're correct, or if everyone else is completely wrong (it happens!) then post. You may get some reputation, you may not. It doesn't matter. What you have done in this situation is attempt to solve the answer for yourself and (hopefully) dispassionately assessed your own abilities against other people. *Pay attention to what they write.* Your own desire to learn and attempt to solve a problem and the community's knowledge are a potent combination when combined.

Other's have stated here that you're not going to get reputation or benefit from answering questions until you have some expertise in some language. You probably won't get much reputation but you will benefit by attempting the problems and viewing, testing, and remembering other's solutions to those same problems.

Good luck!

Comment: Solid advice, every time someone posts a better answer than you, you gain knowledge, and given that you've just been working on the problem, that knowledge is all the more likely to sink in.

Comment: Also even if you are with less experience than some of the people on SO, this does not mean that you could not provide a fresh look on the question from a different angle.

Comment: I could not have said it better myself. I may have lots of reputation *now*, but I started by *reading* the answers from others to questions I did not know... and that's how I *expanded* my knowledge, to the point where today I am pretty confident in my primary language (and thus switching to another).

Answer (score 31):

Develop some skillz first.  Then you'll be in a position to be helpful to others.

Merely asking questions requires some fundamental expert knowledge of your craft.  Answering questions, even more so.

In my experience, if I'm not actively working at least at a semi-professional level in the technology that the asker is asking about, I'm not effective at answering.

Comment: I like the "Merely asking questions requires some fundamental expert knowledge of your craft" part.  Being able to ask a half-intelligent question does show that one has already progressed a fair amount in their journey to being a rock star.

Answer (score 24):

## Bad advice

1. Go to the front page. Alternatively, to the Questions tab or your favorite tag's page (**sort by newest**).
2. Spam <kbd>F5</kbd> and watch for **stupid questions**. Use **favorite tags** for highlighting.
3. There're plenty of noob questions incoming from users who don't bother to use SO's search or Google.
4. When you see yet another stupid question, **answer it quickly**. Write a simple answer (no more than several sentences), then improve. Edits within 5 minutes are not displayed, use it for your advantage.
5. If you don't know the answer, but the question still looks incredibly stupid, **just Google it**. Most likely, you'll find an answer on the first Google page. Just copy it. Providing link is optional.
6. **Upvote the stupid question**. It means more traffic and more upvotes.
7. Usual cheese applies: strategical **downvoting of opponents** (learn the period of free reversal), **obnoxious formatting**, lists etc.
8. When you answer a question, never return, **never reply to comments**, unless you start receiving dozens of downvotes (at 1:5 upvote to downvote ratio you can actually lose points, but that's almost impossible). It's just a waste of time.
9. Stupid questions **can get closed** or even deleted, but don't worry, it's unlikely to affect you in any way. There's so much garbage that mods and high-rep users can't do anything about it.
10. When you get to **200 reputation limit** (it may take several hours with this strategy), stop. Getting upvotes only from accepted answers isn't worth it. Repeat tomorrow.

Eventually, you'll <s>farm lots of reputation in no time</s> leave StackOverflow and never come back. Thank you for contributing to nearing StackOverflow's doom and have a nice day.

Comment: [Six simple tips to get Stack Overflow reputation fast](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17204/six-simple-tips-to-get-stack-overflow-reputation-fast)

Comment: @BoltClock Yes, my answer is a compilation of several posts about abusing (or stopping to abuse) SO's features and encouraging (or stopping to encourage) bad user behavior. With the recent influx of meta posts about SO going down the drain, finding them is as easy as ever.

Comment: What is this garbage...

Comment: This is so funny!

Answer (score 20):

Stack Overflow is an excellent vehicle for escaping mediocrity, but it takes time and effort. I am definitely a mediocre programmer (at best). I am self taught and have no formal training of any kind whatsoever in computer related fields. However, I have improved a lot since discovering SO and answering questions.

I have found that the key to being able to answer questions and gain rep amongst more experienced and highly trained peers is to use your own experience and filter more.

My language of choice is PHP for many reasons. However I started by answering questions in the  [zend-framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zend-framework) tag as I was using it for a couple of projects I was working on at the time. I found my hard won experience in the framework was useful for helping out others who were encountering problems I had already come across.

I later found it beneficial to filter on portions of the PHP language that I happen to be using a lot, it helped to improve my knowledge and hence my code. So, I would filter on, say, [PHP and DateTime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php%2bdatetime) as lately my projects seem to involve the DateTime classes. Doing this narrows down the number of areas you need good knowledge in to provide useful answers. The research you do to answer the questions will quickly improve your skills in your chosen tag/sub-tag.

I would recommend setting up a test VM that you can run tests, benchmarks and code on to test your answers without polluting your working environment. That way you can be pretty sure that you are providing working answers. This takes a bit of time, so you won't be [TFGIW](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem), which is a good thing.

Also read good answers and hang around in chat, you will learn far more than you expect that way.

I just thought an answer from somebody who feels they are in the same boat as you would be encouraging. The simple strategies I have outlined above will get me through the 10k barrier sometime during the next few months. Quite an achievement for somebody with no training and one of which I am quietly proud.

Comment: `"I am self taught and have no formal training of any kind whatsoever in computer related fields"` wow, that is an inspiration!

Comment: No programmers are "self-taught".  **It's an in-built skill like singing, or being tall.** You either have it or not. You can no more "learn" programming than you can "learn" to be sexy or "learn" to sing. (Regarding programming "courses" - it's risible. Like "creative writing" courses for people who "want to be poets" - staggeringly stupid.)  PHP is not programming, that's just scripting.  (Just teasing there, bro :) All programming "languages" are the same, of course.)

Comment: @vasco makes an outstanding point that SO is about **specialities**. I have vast knowledge about iOS [which is a stupid waste of time, by the way] but I am only able to answer a few microscopic specialities within that.  Well said, vasco.

Comment: Joe - nonsense. Programming is absolutely not an inbuilt skill. It is almost the opposite. You can have an aptitude for analytics, or structured thought, but anyone can be taught programming. At any age.

Comment: @JoeBlow I believe you can have an aptitude for programming, but it still needs to be learned. I know, I have put a lot of effort into learning over the past 34 years, from basic to Z80 assembler to Pascal and many others. It is important to have the right mindset though, many people couldn't think logically if their lives depended on it.

Comment: @likejiujitsu - one of the best developers in our company has a Philosophy degree. To the best of my knowledge, he's fully self taught.

Comment: @JoeBlow - you can have a singing voice. But it needs to be trained to sing well. (having - in the past - a good singing talent - I can tell you there's a world of difference between someone with talent and someone with professional singing training). Same with programming. It's a combination of ability and learning.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I mostly agree, but there's something like an IQ test for programming.  Jeff Atwood blogged about a [programming aptitude test](http://blog.codinghorror.com/separating-programming-sheep-from-non-programming-goats/) at one point.  I don't think that says anything more about your ultimate abilities than an IQ test does, but it might measure how much of a challenge you're up against to learn something that doesn't naturally settle with your perceptual framework.

Comment: @RoryAlsop - I couldn't disagree more, I can point out examples everywhere of people around me who can't program and can't be taught to program. And no, I'm not talking about people where I work who are employed as programmers :)

Comment: @JoeBlow Tangent to your point, but a decent or better poetry/writing class and a decent or better programming course of study should have in common learning the tools, the craft, and looking at sources. You have a tricked-out brain, or you have inspiration, or ability, but what then?  Here is where craft comes in: not all writers or programmers are clever, but if competent, they do know what goes where, and why.  And 'source code': you can write/program without knowing how the best have done it, but looking at the best of the best (source, texts) is a great first (and 2nd, 3rd, ...) step.

Comment: Hi @belacqua.  It's a tricky business. I have a feeling **the world is very "unfair'**.  Consider what DVK said about singing voices: I wish it was true but it's the opposite of the truth.  You either are Paul McCartney, Julie Andrews, Maria Callas .. or you're not.  Certainly musicians practice basically all their waking lives, but that's **even more tragic** - all the #2 guitarists in the world practice 3000 hours a year, but they'll never ever be joe walsh, jimi hendrix .. or buckethead! Music and singing in particular is the ultimate example of "you have it or not, that's it."...

Comment: ...so for me I believe what i said in my first comment above. Anyway, all the more reason that professional engineering chat resources like SO are critically important; and I utterly agree with what you say about the critical importance of other's source code and so on. (Better and better programmers have more and more open midns, and want to see EVERYTHING.)  So uh .. go, stackoverflow!

Comment: @JoeBlow I agree that things are unfair in the sense you're talking about; those who are borderline equipped (mentally et al.) at a relevant point in time aren't likely to be "great". Yet I think there is a huge amount achievable with targeted study & consistent practice.  If deficits are large, the requisite work would sink anyone w/o another exceptional ability: determination, optimism, etc.. To your point, those who don't 'have it' are probably going to employ naive, unproductive study. Mentors, SO, etc. can help. One who *self-assesses* as mediocre is likely positioned to gain a lot.

Comment: @belac - yes, for sure you're totally correct. That's an excellent point about individuals who self-assess as mediocre. Excellent. It's fascinating that people at the very top (of anything) are often dismissive about their own knowledge and-or talents. In any event, a reminder of how ridiculously important SO is to workflow todays.

Comment: I heard a phrase that struck a chord with me yesterday. [Fraud Syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impostor_syndrome) may explain why some people self assess as mediocre. It doesn't really add to this discussion, but struck me as interesting given @belacqua's phraseology.

Answer (score 11):

A lot of the answers and comments say to avoid the basic questions.

If you want to learn how to program better, I think the basic questions are actually a *good* place to start.  The key is not simply answering them to win the race.  The key is providing informative answers that explain the problem, along with work-arounds and fixes.  You don't have to be incredibly verbose to do this.  The additional explanation should help you, the OP, and anyone who stumbles across the question.  Remember:  on the easier questions your skill and expertise are probably as good as anyone else's.

For me personally, Stack Overflow has increased my abilities to explain concepts and provided well-needed patience in working with people who are not as knowledgeable as I am.  I happen to think that being able to explain code and working with other people are important skills for a developer -- and more important than Stack Overflow points.  Such skills will probably result in more points as well.

Answer (score 10):

A mediocre programmer should probably be worried more about becoming a better programmer, not scoring points on SO

Comment: This is more of a comment than an answer; and it's a comment that's already been mentioned, in a lot more detail, in most of the answers... I'm sorry but I don't think this adds anything to the discussion

Comment: This is a great answer in my opinion. It's right to the point. Rep is a by-product of expertise and participation, not the goal itself.

Answer (score 7):

Just ask a question whenever you get really stuck on a problem with your code - say, you've spent a day or at least half a day trying to figure it out, and haven't been able to.  If you're a mediocre programmer, these situations should happen fairly frequently.  If you're good about providing enough code for others to figure out your problems, without providing so much that people don't bother, your questions will accumulate a few upvotes and you'll gain rep.

If you really pay attention to the answers and understand them, you'll gain expertise as well.

Comment: Sometimes the key to the solution lies in the attempt to give all the information so that another guy could help you. While trying to formulate my questions I often find the solution/culprit myself.

Answer (score 7):

Regarding building reputation points posting the image "visual representation of joins" seems to generally work!

- [+37](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19646665/73226)
- [+48](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19646594/73226)
- [+121](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3183687/73226)
- [+441](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6188334/73226)
- [+589](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16598900/73226)
- [+66](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17692215/73226)

Answer (score 5):

There is not necessarily any connection between SO points and programming knowledge. Particularly, there is no connection between SO points and *useful* knowledge.

The superior way to get points is to find a really obscure, completely pointless language mechanism, then ask a naive question about it. For example, look at the [all-time top voted questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=votes&pageSize=50) at the [c](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c) tag.

- Number 1 is about an obscure operator that actually doesn't exist. It is nonsense knowledge with no relevance for future readers.
- Number 2 is another nonsense sequence of operators that no sane person would use in the real world.
- Number 5 is a classic C joke that people have made fun of since the 1970s. Again nonsense code and a well-known oddity you've been able to read about in the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/joke.html) for ages.
- Number 6 is another obscure sequence of operators. Again nonsense and obfuscation.

And so on.

As you hopefully can see, there's no relation between the usefulness of the question and the points received. Completely useless knowledge is rewarded approximately 100 times higher than useful knowledge.

To demonstrate my theory, I have now launched an experiment. I shamelessly posted a [Q&A on another completely pointless language mechanism](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23825603/what-is-the-meaning-of-these-strange-question-marks) and I would be surprised if I don't get a bunch of upvotes for sharing this completely useless knowledge. During the time I've been spell-checking this meta post, I've already received 9 upvotes.

That's what SO points are worth.

Answer (score 4):

Approach each question that you find interesting in a way like if it is your own quesiton.

1. See if you could formulate/explain the question in a better way, without changing its meaning - if so, do not hesitate to edit the question.
2. See if you could find similar questions on SO. If so - do not hesitate to give references to them.
3. See if you could give general advice on the question, based on your own experience and expertise. Do not hesitate to put answers that does not include code. If you wish to add code, you could always do this later, by editing your answer.
4. Do not give up/get frustrated if the OP selects another answer as a solution, even if you find your answer being more comprehensive than the accepted solution.
5. Do not hesitate to dive into areas/topics where you have little to no expertise. You might be able to answer some of these questions, based on your current experience and expertise, with some aid from online API documentation, etc.

Comment: Excellent -- #5 is what I *attempt* to do as well. Sometimes I use Google to read up on languages, functions, libraries, and algorithms -- and I'm not afraid to *not* answer if that leads to nothing.

Answer (score 4):

Build expertise and gain a reputation.
There are a LOT of assumptions in that statement.

If you want to become a better programmer, identify your assumptions and check back against them.

```
Assumption 1. You gain a rep here for expertise. Facts not in evidence
Assumption 2. You can't gain a rep without expertise. Facts not in evidence
Assumption 3. Mediocre = inexperienced. Wrong, mediocre is crap despite experience...
```

So given just these three assumptions are totally invalid, I'm very surprised this question got re-opened.

Build expertise, THEN gain a reputation, is the answer to the question you should have asked.

Answer (score 4):

Specialize

Whenever your are on a specific project at work or at home. Dig into a technology/pattern/best practice and then stick to the tags related to that item for a while and the points will come easy.

Answer (score 4):

Do some coding (Pick any one popular language, your choice), Fail, Start SO'ing (Remember SO'ing is not just about answering question, it is also about asking questions too) Do some more coding, Fail, More So'ing Are you enjoying? If yes, then do some more coding, More SO'ing Do algorithms, Do Data Structures, More SO'ing, Fail, More coding.., Go Github, Go Topcoder Practice Problems, More SO'ing Still Enjoying? If yes, then eat think drink sleep code, plenty of more coding, More SO'ing, Do math, Fail, More coding, More SO'ing, More Math, More Algorithms, More Data Structures, More and More SO'ing hmmmmm Are you still a mediocre programmer? If yes and enjoying, repeat the above else quit coding. Have you become a decent programmer? O! you didn't realize that as a part of doing all of the above the reputation on SO came as a by-product.

Answer (score 4):

> How can a programmer of average ability (mediocre) build expertise

## Noway.

There is no way to build expertise hanging around some site.
Quite contrary, I see too much people who built their "expertize" straight from Stack Overflow. They answer questions on the matters they **never laid their hands upon.** They understand nothing but can only repeat some sermon they've learned. The value of their answers is from none to harmful. That's a foul shame for the site.

Own programming experience is the only way to get expertize.

> and reputation points on Stack Overflow

Get a life. You don't need reputation on Stack Overflow. There is not a single reason for it. Your desire is just a shameful consequence of site authorities, who overplayed with "gamification". While they should encourage people to share the knowledge, they encourage people to get points.

Comment: This is the only answer I agree with even though it is written with a rude condescending tone. To me it seems clear that the OP is more concerned with reputation points than actual expertise. I think you and I have very similar feelings about SO in general, although without the gamification I have doubt that the site would be successful at all.

Answer (score 1):

Mediocre schmediocre.

There is no such concept like 'mediocre'. Everyone knows something well, or good/talented in one or more subjects - even if they lack the knowledge and talent in a million subjects. Because they are not well-off in a DETERMINED set of subjects, people call them 'mediocre'. But, as it always is, neither the determined set of subjects to decide whether someone is not 'mediocre' is ever enough, nor it is an universal answer to any question or situation.

Case in point - everyone is running around and barfing OOP solutions to every single freaking problem. Its an OOP world baby, and because it is 'the' thing, everything must be OOP ! Including ALL data which is being processed in any application !!

The hard reality in trenches is way too different from this holistic approach to coding. In reality, there is no point to casting most of the data into objects, because there is no notable benefit from casting data which has no interdependent parts into an object at all.

In fact most of the time people lose a lot from code readability, ease of maintenance, integration due to whipping all data into objects, which then become entities of themselves to keep track of, and maintain in the long run, instead of merely being 'data'.

For example you wont be doing anything useful by casting the data of an order in an ecommerce site into an object. A lot of independent data, merely a collection of various independent fields ranging from payment processor involved to amount processed, address and whatnot.

All you need are freaking associative arrays. And actually in a lot of languages, you can get this data directly as associative array from the database layer. Its as simple as that. Need to make a csv ? Just implode rows of data with ','. Need to export to another representation ? Just export with their labels.

If you had an object, you would need to take account of the structure of the class you used for representing the object, and account for any necessary method which you may have needed to do these, or anything similar.

Crude example. but enough.

So you may be someone who is handling such data every day at work.

Slap your easier, more useful, 'unconventional' answer to a question where a lot of 'smart' guys are fighting with object representations of some simple data. Solve things simply.

In short :

Answer in the way you know BETTER. You dont have to answer in a way what OTHERS know 'better'. Or think they know better.

Comment: Unfortunately, OOP isn't just about where to store data and how to shovel it around, but more importantly it's about program design. "Store everything in arrays" might be a sound idea for some tasks, but a horrible idea for others. A mediocre programmer isn't experienced enough to tell. You need _lots_ of experience before you can do good program design on your own.

Comment: Of course it isnt. This, in case you have not noticed, was an EXAMPLE.

Comment: Is it only me, or you just wrote a two-sentence answer to the question, just to include a 6-paragraph OOP rant? :D

Comment: It is just you.

Answer (score 0):

When did accumulating points on stack overflow become more important than actually learning something important? and getting stuff to work? :O

Comment: Agreed, although this isn't much of answer, and this sentiment is already pretty well-covered by the comments, the longer answers, and [one shorter one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/255978/). You're not really adding anything.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I'll go ahead and provide an idea no one has offered. Consider learning a new less developed language! Pick something really esoteric, like [Lua](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lua_(programming_language)). Then as you're learning don't ask, *"what questions could I learn from"*, but instead *"what questions can I conceive of **someone** asking or upvoting?"*

For instance, let's say that you're programming and you get a really crappy error,

> attempt to concatenate global 'path' (a nil value)

You may immediately figure out what that error means, but that doesn't mean you lost the potential to ask a question. Sure someone else may find that question useful, but more importantly you'll get an immediate reward if only you phrase it right.

My [most upvoted question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6157497/124486) is a total stinker, but just look at how much EXP I got from it!! And, moreover, it'll probably help someone out too. I've considered on numerous occasions submitting a doc patch on `console.log` to clearly answer this often asked question -- but, why would I do that? I'm at 96 upvotes **AND counting!!!**