# How important is an explanation when user is asking for specific code (like a query)?

Tags: discussion

Yesterday, I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26490556/how-to-retrieve-the-total-number-occurances-of-a-value/26490802#26490802).

At about the same time, another user and I gave the same query as an answer. Mine was not accepted, and I'm okay with that because the accepted answer was not wrong.

However, I thought at the time I gave a better answer because I gave a bit of explanation as well as an SQLFiddle as proof that it works as suggested.

Is it a waste of my time to explain my answer, in a situation where all the OP is looking for is a working query? Or is it better practice to continue giving answers as I did?

Comment: It's always better to explain.

Comment: @Ben So, in a situation like this, I'm just SOL on an accepted answer? Again, the accepted one isn't wrong, so there's really no case for concern, but it is kind of discouraging to put a little extra effort into an answer that goes unnoticed.

Comment: It happens @McAdam; given the amount of searching the OP did before asking that question I'm not surprised that they went for the answer they could copy and paste. However, it'll help you in the longer run. You'll get higher _average_ scores for your answers and you'll learn a lot more in the process, [I did](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/254908/458741).

Comment: @Ben thanks for the input. I could have given a copy-paste answer, but didn't feel it would help the OP at all moving forward. When I saw that type of answer accepted, I just wanted to make sure I was doing the right thing. I'm not going to fight over fake points, but I do think it's important to build my reputation when I can, because it is an added credibility to my answers moving forward.

Comment: It's more important than the actual code

Comment: @McAdam331 Personally I would have gone with your answer, the other answer for some reason sets an alias on `prefered_type` when it's not needed but doesn't bother to set an alias on the aggregated column. It's just the [Fastest Gun in the West Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9731/fastest-gun-in-the-west-problem).

Comment: @McAdam331 If you think your answer is better, then downvote the other one, even if it is accepted. Downvotes and upvotes for answers by themselves should show its usefulness, but when combined with other answers to the same problem, should be comparative to the other answers as well.

Comment: @TylerH fair enough. It just seemed hard to downvote something that was correct, even though it may not have been of the best quality. That being said though, on a website like this that is used often for learning quality is just as important as accuracy.

Comment: @McAdam331: Downvoting does not say "That is wrong", but "This answer is not useful". A correct answer can be not useful, and a wrong one can be helpful (Correct or comment, depending on the case, for the second kind). Though I set a higher bar for downvoting "competing" answers on the questions I answered than for questions where I did not. BTW: It does not seem you really missed out on any reps by now.

Comment: @Deduplicator no, I most certainly have not anymore. My score on that answer was 0 when I asked this question, and is now at 11. I was not asking for that, but I trust the experience and knowledge of the stack community to use their votes properly. If anything, this has helped me realize my true reason for spending time here, and how to utilize that time in the most productive way.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You will have the answer to your question if you answer first to *"why am I here ?"*

- If you are looking only/mostly for "rep" *points* then answer fast, to as many questions as you can. It won't "educate" the OP, nor anyone coming to that question from a search on the Internet. It won't help you to improve your technicals skills or writing skills. And it won't increase the overall quality of SO. But it will definitively increase your score.
- On the other hand, if you are looking here for something more than just gather unicorn points, then you definitively should spend the necessary time to explain your answer.

If necessary, there is a famous quote (mis)attributed to Albert Einstein that should encourage you to continue the way you do it now: *"If you can't explain it simply, you don't understand it well enough."*

Comment: You get quite a few unicorn points with an explanation as well, but yes, it does sometimes mean you lose FGITW.

Comment: +1 If SO points could be transferred into frequent flier miles, this conversation would be completely different.

Comment: Excellent points. I didn't expect this sort of reaction to my question - I didn't mean to sound like a child being discouraged over one unaccepted answer, but wanted to turn to the rest of the community to make sure I'm doing this right. I am here to learn as well as teach. I've retracted several answers that I felt weren't correct or in some cases turned out to be wrong, but this one hit a soft spot for me. I will keep doing what I'm doing: answering questions to share my knowledge. Even if it's unaccepted, I hope they can still help people.

Comment: That quote misattributed to Einstein is a favorite of pointy-haired bosses who won't understand an explanation. Of course, it's not that *they* do not understand. It's that *you* are explaining badly. Here's a quote *really* [from Einstein](https://www.stmarys-ca.edu/sites/default/files/attachments/files/On_The_Method_of_Theoretical_Physics.pdf): "It can scarcely be denied that the supreme goal of all theory is to make the irreducible basic elements as simple and as few as possible **without having to surrender the adequate representation of a single datum of experience.**" (Emphasis mine.)

Comment: @Louis I agree: the attribution of this quote is rather _doubtful_. As of its meaning, I tend to understand it the other way around: _"you only have understood something once you can explain it clearly"_. From my personal experience, it is rather common, while trying to explain something, to discover some subtleties or to feel the need of clarifying some details about a not so-obvious corner case. *That* are a very good reasons both for being here on SO *and* to take time to explain my answers.

Comment: +1: I must confess I oscillate between the two. Sometimes I want to see unicorn numbers go up, sometimes I really feel like the question is helping me assess my knowledge and/or abilities and I take a long time checking, answering, etc. Thanks for the input @McAdam331, and thanks for the answer!

Comment: The question linked to has since been removed and I have lost all the reputation. While I admittedly gained upvotes I didn't need (18), I just instantly lost all 180 of those points.