# Why is there only one way to gain reputation?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, reputation

As I have progressed with my involvement with Stack Overflow more and more of my effort is spent gardening as opposed to answering questions. Everyone once in a while I'll see something I know the answer to, but I spend way more time casting close votes, burning through the review queue, and trying to help people ask better questions.

Several high rep users have indicated that the days of "low hanging fruit" and "easy rep" questions are over. As on and off member for 3 years I agree with this statement. Most of the commonly asked questions have been asked. Most of the new posts that can be considered questions at all are duplicates or variants of those questions. Not to be misunderstood this is a good thing its an indication that the site is moving towards its stated goal, but it does change a lot of the dynamics of participation.

From what I understand reputation indicates your SO standing as judged by your peers, but only in respect to the answers you provide. The current system requires this reputation to be awarded moderating privileges. To more effectively do the activities that so desperately need done on this site a user needs these moderating privileges. This means the only way to be a effective moderator is to answer lots of questions. This is the rub Stack Overflow seems to be approaching a post answering world. What happens when stack overflow does what it set out to do and everything is answered?

With that said my question is, if reputation is an indicator of your involvement and answering questions is becoming less important as the library becomes more comprehensive why does answering questions remain the primary vehicle for gaining reputation?

### Edit

I think there was some misunderstanding regarding the question above. I'd like to clarify. I believe the reputation system as it stands provides perverse incentive for low quality answers . Additionally it encourages upvoting of bad questions to get traction/visibility for those answers. This applies to even to folks who's ultimate goal is to do the right thing. I haven't accepted an answer yet because most of the answers are discussion, but no one(as of the date of this edit) has directly answered my question which is:

*What is the rationale for this system?*

and more specifically:

*Why leaving it that way is better than any proposed alternative?*

Comment: Related:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251084/1079354

Comment: Me personally, as long as I stay above 3k, I don't care about rep. I'm perfectly happy close-voting and "gardening" the site with no rep reward.

Comment: Gunr, I explicitly give away (bounty) my huge number of points, because it's now way uncool to have "points on a pro-sumption site". It's the same "reverse snobbery" thing where it's now cool to just leave comments with a decisive answer, if you're an expert, rather than using the "answer" mechanism.

Comment: *"answering questions is becoming less important"* Whoa there, [citation-needed]

Comment: Remotely related: [How to decide which questions I should not answer?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254549)

Comment: Let's say for some economic reason, having a high score on SO is important.  (It lends prestige in your industry; you need to get more dates - whatever.) In that case the best thing to do is assign some of your best subordinates (ideally top experts in the field in question), to answer questions on your behalf for N hours a week. This is one of those interesting freakanomics things where everything benefits. The fundamental aim of a pro-sumption site like this is to make profit for the shareholders: that aspect would benefit. The "global-social" aim is to "have good information/answers".....

Comment: ....on hand on the internet; that would benefit. The "current problems" about essentially unprofessionalism, newbie-floods etc, would hugely benefit.  {What I mean by that is the current "lord of the flies" -esque vibe would be replaced by cool professionals racking up results and then going home to the spouse and kids.} And you would benefit from a high score (for whatever reason you want that).  Further, your employees would benefit, etc.

Comment: Oh, and a final point the actual economic benefit of having A High SO Score, would be more quantifiable if you were paying per hour to your subordinates to achieve that. Perhaps SO will be the first pro-sumption site where such "paid engineering" will come to the fore?

Comment: Looking at how seemingly trivial stuff gets upvoted in tags that are pretty highly frequented, I think there is also quite a difference in your "real" reputation given which tags you "hang out with". In one answering 50 questions might give you 5k after a while, while in another answering 50 questions awards you with 25k after a while.

Comment: related question - http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/256742/gamification-rules-have-to-be-changed-aiming-quality-not-quantity?cb=1

Comment: I completely disagree with the premise that all the important or interesting questions have been asked, or even all the questions that are easy for you to answer, assuming that you're actually a professional programmer.  That would imply that all of the important or interesting programming problems have been solved, which is not the case.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I never said all the important or interesting questions were answered. But you would acknowledge that compared to the *Big Bang* of Stack Overflow in terms of *Low Hanging Fruit* the landscape is much different. If you accept that as time passes the library becomes more comprehensive its not a stretch to assume that number of interesting/important questions become fewer and fewer.

Comment: The difference is that in the past, "low hanging fruit" was upvoted, perhaps wrongly, but that was the case.  If you accept that as time passes the library becomes more comprehensive, you must also accept that programmers are no longer necessary.  (If you can't tell, I reject your premise.)

Comment: If you can't tell, I do not disagree with your disagreement with the straw man you've created. I'm not asking what to do with the final state of the SO world, but rather what to do in the interim. How do you encourage people to garden low-traffic, low-quality tags? Edit/Close existing questions? There is a great post related to this one that just came up on "Encouraging Quality over Quantity" by using the reputation system.

Comment: Except that it isn't a straw man.  People do earn reputation by answering good questions, even today.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I find your comments to be inflammatory as such I am not going to continue engaging with you in this thread. I would encourage you to read my edit as it clarifies my intentions in asking this question. Good Luck!

Comment: Inflammatory because I disagree with your premise?  You have multiple badges for nice question and nice answer, so you yourself are a counterexample of your own premise.  And I did read your edit prior to my first comment on this post.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg you make all valid points. The only issue is they are unrelated to the discussion. If you want some premises to attack I will simplify for you. People want rep. Answering is the only real way to get rep. Useful answering is getting harder to do. More people want rep than want quality. Answering easy questions(regardless of quality) is a more effective way to get this rep. This is where I lose you. Do you disagree with one or more of these? Do you think highly upvoted answers are as attainable as they were 4 years ago? Do you think the system is fine like it is?

Comment: You are correct on the spot where you lose me, nsfyn55, but perhaps it is due to the tag that in which I participate, R.  There,  you'll find that answers to low-ball questions are not highly upvoted -- with one huge exception, where your answer shows insight that is not especially easy to see beforehand.  One-liners can get 10 or 20 upvotes.  As for whether it is possible to get as many votes for an answer as was garnered for a 4-year-old, well, you might have to wait four years to find out.

Comment: If this question is allowed to ask on StackOverflow, then you may get  155 (31x5) reputations ;)

Answer (score 36):

There's a guy who, for awhile, trolled the "featured questions" page, researched and answered the questions there, and was earning over 1000 rep per day.  You could do the same.

Or, there's the [unanswered questions](https://stackoverflow.com/unanswered) page, with 1.7 million unanswered questions and counting.  There's got to be some decent questions in there somewhere that could be answered comprehensively, which would yield substantial reputation.

Good answers are always rewarded, in my experience.  Alas, few want to take the time.

Comment: trolled or trawled ? Or maybe I've been trolled.

Comment: @dilbert Nah, this is a valid use of the word 'trolling' - it's like trawling but for way smaller numbers (like you troll for a single fish, you trawl for many). That said, I'm going back to my beer before it gets warm.

Comment: Last I checked, 200 was the maximum possible reputation one could earn per day. Was this during the earlier days of SO?

Comment: I'm not complaining about my score or the difficulty of gaining reputation. I am pointing out a misaligned incentive specifically as it relates to this site's logical conclusion. Meta is full of posts about the symptons(repwhoring, signal/noise, bad answers, lack of interest in non rep based activities). How many posts/comments do you think you could find on meta that suggested punishing someone for answering a bad question? Why are they so quick to go to the rod when they clearly have a carrot that works?

Comment: @Klompengard Bounties and the reputation you gain from an accepted answer aren't counted towards the 200 point cap. Which is exactly why 'trolling the "featured questions" page' is a way to get more points per day.

Comment: It was [MrGomez](http://stackoverflow.com/users/517815/mrgomez).

Comment: It has been *several* different people. But yeah, [MrGomez was certainly one of them](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/127021/is-excessive-bounty-hunting-good-etiquette).

Comment: I thought there was a reputation cap of 250 or so?

Comment: @0x499602D2 bounties and accepted answer points aren't capped, only upvotes.

Comment: "Good answers are always rewarded" is simply not true. Unless you jump off your pants extensively advertising your answer, showing off on meta, etc., nobody ever notice your job. On the other hand, such advertising can give you the same reward for a crappy answer on a duplicated bike shed question. Why bother then?

Comment: The answer avoids discussing the quantitative effects. Most of the featured questions have already a good answer and many unanwsered questions are abandoned or very specific or just plain boring... it could be much harder now to get a certain amount of rep than it was years ago.

Comment: If he trolled, was he being a troll?

Answer (score 11):

I agree with much of what you are saying and am in a similar boat.  I actually did join 4.5 years ago when there were some good questions left, but I did not have the time back then to answer. I spend most of my time now editing, reviewing and fixing up.  I maybe provide 1 or 2 answers a day.

So I don't think it is so important this reputation thing.  These days, it is really about trying to keep this site viable.  Trying to prevent the weeds (the questions demonstrating no effort) from choking the whole system.  Keeping the quality up.  That is really the fruit of one's work with SO.  After all, I just don't contribute, I actually use the site when I have a problem.  So that is enough motivation for me.

The other way in which reputation is skewed these days is that it does not talk about today.  Many original users / high rep users sit back and pile up reputation for older questions and answers without having to do any work.  There are more advanced metrics to capture current activity, but the reputation number is the one which everyone sees when they come to the site.  So in that sense too, reputation does not capture who is actively contributing to the site.  Once could reset everyone's reputation to 0 (JUST KIDDING!).  Trying posting that as a question on MSO and see how many downvotes you can get in such a short time.  You'd set the record I am sure.  Reputation is just a number.  Once you have the privileges you feel you need, it is just gravy after that.  Anyone (at least in theory) has a shot at becoming a mod once they reach 3K.

Comment: So the only question left is how difficult it is nowadays to get to 3K. I guess one needs at least around 100-200 average answers for that. Now if the average number of upvotes per answer are going down so the number of answers (or questions) you need will go up. Do they go down? I have to check.

Comment: @Trilarion Not encouraging it ... but one can get 1K solely by editing poor questions and answers.  To me that seemed a little strange in the early days.  Now I think it is a little bit more justified because of the benefit it creates for the site.

Answer (score 10):

There are other ways to be rewarded with rep points for a routine but useful work. E.g., improving tag wikis. There's a lot of work to do to make them better and actually useful. You'll get 2 points per each accepted edit.

I agree that it's certainly more difficult to score rep points these days, but it's not impossible. I've myself started actively asking and answering less than a year ago. I noticed some other guys who started after me and have already passed the 20K mark.

Do not hesitate to *ask* a question, you may get substantial rep points for that too. You certainly deal with some problems in your daily work, each of them might be a good candidate for a question. You just need to reasonably avoid duplicates.

Comment: I always thought that as soon as you have enough reputation to not need edits to be accepted by others, you won't get the 2 rep.

Comment: @PlasmaHH, you still get points for accepted tag wiki edits. I'm close to 20K and I still do. That probably will stop after 20K. I don't know if there is a cap on the number of edits, I've done just about a dozen.

Comment: ah ok, I am not doing much tag wiki stuff. I would assume just as with normal edits, once you are capable of not needing others to approve/accept your edits, you won't get those reps. Though I don't know if this will ever happen for tag edits.

Comment: Once you've 2k reputations, your edits will directly get approved and you want get 2 rep.

Comment: "You'll get 2 points per each accepted edit." - lol. So... 10 years to climb up to 4k point (where you got access to all reviews)? Sorry, but improving tag wikis is extremely time taking with very little reward.

Comment: @MarcinWolny, nevertheless, from what I can tell it's a quite popular thing to "farm" reputation by editing question/answers for spelling/formatting, which also gives 2 points per approved edit. I can't see why this can't be applied to wikis with the same success. Most of wikis do need editing for good content, so that'd be a good deed.

Comment: @Noseratio - because wikis need quality content, not random edits. As far as I can tell: grammar/formatting/spelling was already fixed on vast majority of them, what's needed now is adding a proper "meat" to the pages, and that takes A LOT of time. Time for which you get 2 reputation points as a reward. >_>

Comment: @MarcinWolny, this might be true. At least, for my few wiki edits, the quality was the goal, as I'm constantly referring to those in my answers.

Comment: Sorry, I'm confused by the term tag wiki. Are we talking about question tags or are tags/tagging for wikis a separate thing? Everyone learns once.....

Comment: @sss4r, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/webbrowser-control/info) is an example of tag wiki. You can edit it to improve, and your edits will be reviewed by peers.

Comment: Thank you. Makes perfect sense to me now.