# Should it be strongly recommended to upvote the question you just edited?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, edits, upvotes

Let us assume someone encounters a question which he believes could use some clarification to  become good. He edits the question, is happy with the result -> should he not upvote the question along with everyone who reviewed and accepted the edits (and everyone who refused the edits eventually downvote)? *Obviously he should think the question after edits deserves more visibility.*

For reference, this came to my mind after reading [Why does it seem so hard to accumulate upvotes in SO?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251084/why-does-it-seem-so-hard-to-accumulate-upvotes-in-so)

**Should there not be some kind of incentives to up-vote/down-vote questions**, for example gain some thing if the question you up-voted turn out to be active/useful in a long run or if the question you down-voted gets marked as a duplicate/etc. ?

I know this kind of thing requires to rely on 'community intelligence' and that a lot of wrong people does not make a right, but SO is already made possible by the quality of its community in my humble opinion.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No.

I often edit questions I know little/nothing about, especially when going through the first post review queue. I can improve formatting, correct spelling/grammar issues and format code, but I couldn't tell you if an iOS development question is a good question, and deserves more visibility. All I can tell you (most of the time), if the question is a good fit, on topic, and looks acceptable.

Answer (score 1):

User may edit a question just to add `code markdown`, but it may still keep the question an ordinary/non-interesting question. I don't agree with your opinion as editing may be done to improve grammar, layout, spelling, etc. However, the question may not be useful/interesting in the long run. Closing duplicate questions is more important than down-voting them.

Comment: My point is, why would you bother editing a question which remains ordinary/non-interesting after the edit?

Comment: @laz, I'd say the majority of posts I edit are not worthy of up votes. Why? Because most posts aren't interesting and the ones that are interesting are usually the ones least in need of editing.

Comment: @IazertyuiopI [Common reasons for edits](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing), to fix grammar and spelling mistakes, to clarify the meaning of the post (without changing that meaning), to include additional information only found in comments, etc.

Comment: Well okay, but then there should totally be a moderation tool to give the opportunity to improve the heart of questions and not just their formatting/spelling/etc. For example being able to 'fork' questions like github repositories.