# Shouldn't most questions get at least as many upvotes as their most popular answer?

Tags: discussion, reputation, voting, upvotes

**tl;dr:** If you upvote an anwer, it basically means that the question is worth answering, and if the question is worth answering, why don't you vote up for?

**Long version:**
Ok I was really going to make a duplicate of [Why does it seem so hard to accumulate upvotes on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251084/why-does-it-seem-so-hard-to-accumulate-upvotes-in-so) because hey, it really sucks not being able to comment anywhere before getting 50 rep and most people don't easily give upvote to newcomers (see my profile: 15 questions and hardly 4 total upvotes). But I am not here to complain about my personal case, but rather try to understand a little more the mechanics of this whole "vote questions up" thing:

I think the following question will be a good illustration to my point (didn't take part in it so can't be biased if you wondered): [How to include another XHTML in XHTML using JSF 2.0 Facelets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4792862/how-to-include-another-xhtml-in-xhtml-using-jsf-2-0-facelets)

Here we can see a well formed question with a very good answer. The question got 80 upvotes while the answer got 170. When I see that I am wondering what the 90 people who voted for the answer but not for the question were thinking.

I mean, I can understand that in some cases there can be a very good answer to a bad question, which explains why there would be such a gap. But currently the moderation team is very active and most poor questions are closed right away. And in this particular case I feel like the question is clear and short and not too specific, and since it called for a very interesting answer, it is clearly under-voted.

My opinion is that if we are logical, non closed questions should statistically get at least as much upvotes as their top upvoted answer because if you are upvoting an answer,it basically means that the question is worth answering, and if the question is worth answering, why don't you vote up for?

PS: I am a non native english speaker, feel free to edit & reformulate even drastically.

Comment: A question can just about be worth answering, but without being particularly well-written or helpful to a large number of people.

Comment: Sometimes a question is very interesting and the answers are rather unsatisfying resulting in the question being upvoted higher but more often the question is mediocre but the answers are truly great. In most cases here it may just be much easier a task to pose a question than to answer it. Therefore my guess is that answers are higher valued and that you do not need to have even roughly equal voting on question and answers.

Comment: Related questions from the über-meta: [Why don't people upvote questions they answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/509/164403), [Do you ever not upvote a question that you answer?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19470/164403)

Comment: Don't agree @JonSkeet, because how will you know that it can be helpful to a large number of people? Aside very general questions about Java or PHP, a lot of questions are specific to a subdomain and can still be very helpfull to everybody that develops in this subdomain. Moreover this is not a literature constest. I think "particularly well written" is a little bit too elitist. The shorter, the clearer

Comment: @Aldian: I think I can tell whether or not a question has been well-written in a way which isn't specific to a particular person. Often there are well-written answers to badly-written questions. Want me to find examples? And no, "the shorter, the clearer" is definitely *not* the case. There are places where you need to be brief - and places where crucial information is left out of the question, and needs to be extracted before the question can be answered.

Comment: I wonder how many downvotes I will get for this one? Since I made some research and try to make the question clear, am I getting downvotes because the question is not usefull? Or because you disagree with me? But if you are disagreeing, you should note that folowing your own rules this is not a valid downvoting reason :P

Comment: @JonSkeet in the example I gave, only the first phrase is required. The precision about having tried a lot of things could even have been omitted. Are you saying you agree with all the people that voted up the answer and ignored the question?

Comment: @Aldian: Not necessarily for that example - but I think it's feasible that people can think both a question and answer are "reasonable" but differ in quality sufficiently that one deserves an upvote and the other doesn't. Further, I assumed you were asking about all questions, not just a single example. Do you want me to provide examples of questions which aren't good enough to deserve upvotes, not bad enough to deserve close votes, but which have good answers?

Comment: @Aldian It looks like you might not be aware that [voting on meta](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta) works different then on the main site (in short on meta it usually does just mean agreement or disagreement).

Comment: In fact there is a badge for highly rated answers to downvoted questions.

Comment: I don't understand why this has negative votes. It seems a reasonable question, and doesn't have any duplicates.

Comment: @JBCP ironic punishment?

Comment: nice thought i like it

Answer (score 11):

It's not a very good question, at least for the current de facto community standards. Specifically:

> I have been trying different ways, none of them are working.

If someone asked that question now it would get several "What have you tried?" and "Show us your code" comments and possibly even close votes for not showing enough effort. I don't necessarily agree with this trend but that's how it is.

In general I think it's natural for answers to get more upvotes than questions at least in the long term. If you have a specific problem and the answer gives you the solution, you're likely to upvote the answer and move on. Not everyone has the "power user" mentality to give the entire page an editorial review after they've already gotten their answer.

Comment: A moderator could have passed by and removed the second part of the question. Now what?

Comment: The community is basically saying two opposite things: 1) that good questions should not be too specific and 2) that askers should provide a lot of details about their particular case

Comment: Yeah, I know. Personally I think a question should have code if and only if answering it requires it ("debug my code"), or at most have a very general example to demonstrate the concept. Unfortunately many people can't make a distinction between a general FAQ question and specific code debugging.