# Why can visitors who aren't logged in see answers?

Tags: discussion, questions, upvotes, users, registration

I know a lot of Stack Overflow visitors just get solutions to problems but aren't registered users. I suggest that just users who are logged in could see answers, and if not, they just see the question and how many answers/comments it has.

I think this would be helpful because this should be an incentive for users to up-vote answers that helped them

What do you think about it?

Comment: What would be my motivation to join if I didn't know if the answers were any good? Also, this stuff is all CC-license, I don't know if hiding it behind a registration is even possible.

Comment: Why do you think forcing people to log in would cause them to vote at all?

Comment: @EngineerDollery It's certainly possible, by the terms of the licence.  The licence simply enables anyone who wants to to share the data with other people.  It doesn't *require* anyone to share the data, or mandate that they share it with everyone, unconditionally.  It doesn't even prevent anyone from selling the information, it just prevents someone from stopping someone else from also sharing it with everyone for free.

Comment: `this should be an incentive for users to up-vote answers that helped them` Users with less than 15 rep can't upvote answers anyway. The vast majority of users who are looking at the site without being logged in likely either don't have an account or have one with <15 rep.

Comment: @Servy, that was sort of my point -- if it's cc, and it's hidden behind registration, then someone will simply share the info without the same restrictions, thus circumventing the restriction and rendering it pointless. Therefore, hiding answers behind registration is, to all intents and purposes, impossible. You said that it's not a mandate to share, I say that given the size of our userbase, it's a certainty.

Comment: @EngineerDollery You said that it's not possible.  That's false.  It is possible.  There is nothing in the license that prevents the site from only sharing the content with registered users.  It might prompt someone else to mirror the site and provide the content without registration, sure, but that doesn't prevent SO from requiring registration.  There are plenty of reasons to not do this, but the CC-licence simply isn't one of them.

Comment: People I just wanted to up a discussion point not go against anything. So I agree with point of view of @Oded http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/265740/575643. The meaning of SO is what he said. But I keep in mind that a lot of user that could really contribute to our community keep not doing it because we don't have any restriction to only consumers visitors.

Comment: I know that @DavidRobinson but only consumers visitors never will contribute with SO if do not have any kind of incentive.

Comment: @MarceloFilho No matter if you require registration or not, you cannot force a user to contribute to a community. If he/she wants to contribute, he/she will register an account of his/her own accord and contribute that way. Forcing registration doesn't really accomplish anything, and restricting answer visibility will only hurt SO.

Comment: @user3580294 I agree with you looking the point of view that Google search engine will not index anything anymore, it will be a giant lost to many developers including me. But how I said there are a lot of developers that know the answer of a lot of questions but keep just consuming without up-vote deserved solutions.

Comment: @MarceloFilho Consider this: Would SO have become what it is today if every click to a SO page showed "Register to see the answer!"? I certainly wouldn't have registered -- I would have dismissed the site as "just another registration-only site" and moved on. There are *many* sites like that, and *none* of them have been as successful as SO. Forcing registration would just harm SO and do nothing to accomplish your stated goal.

Comment: @MarceloFilho And I don't think you understand Oded's answer. Voting is **secondary** to the main purpose of the site. Votes are there to help pick a good answer and make sure good answers show up. They should *not* be thought of as the "primary reward" for a good answer. In addition, as I pointed out, forcing users to register does not force them to vote, and as David Robinson stated, you can't upvote anyways until you have a certain amount of rep. Your suggestion doesn't address either of those points.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

The number 1 use case for Stack Overflow is, and has always been:

- A programmers has an issue
- They google for it
- They get a Stack Overflow link
- They follow the link
- They find an answer
- The solve their issue and keep on working

That's what the site is primarily designed for. The reputation and the gamification is all a means to getting good answers for these people.

Comment: help me understand something: why this post (http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251084/why-does-it-seem-so-hard-to-accumulate-upvotes-in-so) got +48 and goes against you said where and my who just up a controversial question got -13.

Comment: @MarceloFilho That question is about users being 'stingy' with voting. Though related, it's really a different topic.

Comment: @MarceloFilho: just because users agree that there is a problem doesn't mean they agree with your solution

Comment: Well, there are the hope extra steps of * After this has happened a few times they realize how cool we are * Join up and contribute enough to * Start voting. But that never happens unless they first find some answer that make it clear how cool we are.

Answer (score 8):

That would create a barrier to entry, and we don't want that here, at least not as far as **reading** content is concerned.

Being an easy to use, highly Google-able resource is out **number one** priority, and requiring log-ins completely undermines that.