# Why is it so hard to begin to contribute to Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion, privileges

I visit SO for a long time and I've recently decided to contribute. I am discovering how the community is working, but my first feedback is that the reputation mechanism is a bit unfair for new contributors.

First privilege you want to access is the 'comment' on another question. It helps to ask for clarification before posting an answer. You need 50 points and I have the feeling that it will take me ages... On the other hand I saw the profile of a user who aked 30+ questions and no anwsers. Many were evaluated as good questions and he has far more privileges than me but obviously this user will never use them. As a result, I don't answer to many questions, because I'm afraid of being off topic (and to see my answer downvoted).

This mechanism relies a lot on [upvotes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251084/why-does-it-seem-so-hard-to-accumulate-upvotes-in-so), but it is difficult to get them on unpopular/rare topics.

Comment: Do realize that if you get 200 rep on *any* SE site (say French.SE for example), it will grant you +100 on all sites.  This will put you over the threshold for commenting.  And there are more things to do with rep than just comment.  You can use it for bounties on questions, or gain sufficient rep to be able to just do edits to fix things up without going through review. Not everything someone does is seen as 'lurking' - and questions are a key part of the Q&A model.

Comment: I'm not sure if *Takes ages*, your current rep and the number of days you have an account on SO are a 100% match....

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If a question needs a comment to be clarified, it's not a very good question, and there's a strong chance that you are wasting your time. Look for good questions, answer those, and you will earn rep.