# Upvote a question more than once in exchange for reputation

Tags: feature-request, questions, reputation, downvotes, upvotes

Just like we can give our reputation to a deserving answer, with bounties, I'd like the ability to upvote a good deserving question in return for being deducted some reputation points of course.

Case in point: [How to generate all the permutations of elements in a list one at a time in Lisp?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49848994/how-to-generate-all-the-permutations-of-elements-in-a-list-one-at-a-time-in-lisp)

The question was badly asked, received downvotes and closure votes; was edited into a more or less good state, attracted an interesting answer and may yet attract more answers.

Yet because of how SO ***is***, regrettably, it stays at the negative score. This is not right. Just as I can pay with my rep to reward a good answer, I want to be able to do so for questions.

I think each additional upvote should cost 5 reputation points. Just like  with the bounties, where there is a one-to-one reputation transfer. If you think it should be 10, I'd go with it too.

> "upvotes are the community's way of telling peers that their content was clear and helpful."

This is what I want to do. Also, the tag is pretty low traffic.

*late edit:* and if you are worrying about ***one man one vote*** principle, this is in no way violating that sacred principle, because I'd pay for it with my rep earned from other people's upvotes -- just like a *representative* in parliament votes with other people's votes too, i.e. those who voted them into the parliament in the first place.

Also, I'd like the same ability for down votes / answers, as well, across the board.

And we can have increasing cost for additional votes, too, to prevent abuse.

Comment: FYI. I didn't google for this; but when I was typing the quesiton there were no candidates at all presented to me that looked remotely relevant. that's why I posted it. if this will turn out to be a duplicate, it won't be *my* fault.

Comment: I'd also appreciate explanation why you think this should *not* be allowed.

Comment: You are equating bounties voting multiple times the same post. It is not the same at all.

Comment: "upvotes are the community's way of telling peers that their content was clear and helpful. "

Comment: And bounties are not for that at all. Bounties are to attract attention to an answer, and reward answerers. But the answer's score doesn't change because they received a bounty.

Comment: @yivi rght. that's why I asked for ability to upvote. I think the fact that the tag is somewhat low traffic may be a significant factor here.

Comment: It's not about views, it's about quality and usefulness. If the community (yes, community, not only you) find it useful, it'd be upvoted naturally. Also, good answers don't make the question automatically good/useful.

Comment: @AndrewT. the fewer views, the fewer chances there are for upvoting. And I want to reward the question that is interesting, not because of the answer - for that we have bonuses already. (I removed the comment about views; apparently some Lisp answer got even more views than 22K) :)

Comment: @Will, if you think the question is interesting and want to "reward" it, a bounty would work. By driving more traffic to it it's more likely  (given that it is an interesting question) that it will receive additional interesting answers and additional upvotes.

Comment: @yivi but I don't want to give bounty to the answer. this is also not so much about rewarding the author with points, but about drawing more attention to the question in the future. because negatively scored questions are far less likely to be opened by a casual reader, I gather.

Comment: You would be both rewarding a good answer to an interesting question, and also the question indirectly. By driving more traffic to it it's liable to be upvoted multiple times. It usually happens with bountied questions. (Unless the bountied question is very bad... but sadly, even then).

Comment: @yivi yes, but, there's minimum 50 rep for the bounty.  I wanted to pay 5 for the up vote, maybe 10. not 50.

Comment: Oh, well. Then it probably wasn't _that_ interesting in the first place. ;) And you have literally **thousands and thousands** of imaginary internet points! Do not be cheap! :P (Just kidding, do what you want with your rep, as long it is not voting multiple times the same post)

Comment: Alternatively, there's [a feature request/discussion on Workplace.SE](https://workplace.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5140/28728) about "rewarding bounty to high-quality post improvement". But that doesn't seem to affect the score of the question though...

Comment: And where will be the limit? 1, 2, 5, 10, 25, 100, 21034???

Comment: You might be interested in Makoto's [question forgiveness](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/253668/help-us-identify-micro-privileges-for-top-users/259077#259077) micro privilege suggestion over on the Main Meta.

Comment: Side note: you pick very questionable "case" to show your point - this post does not look like question useful/interesting to many - 61 views for post featured on meta is *really* low.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov no, that's high, for the lisp tag.

Answer (score 18):

### Strongly disagree.

Something like this would absolutely wreck the meaning of scores from what actually is, perverting it beyond recognition.

For starters, having more rep would give you more power to decide if a question is higher quality or not. And while rep give more privileges, "casting more than one vote" is not an attainable privilege, for a reason. Not even mods or employees can cast more than one vote per post.

By casting multiple votes a user would be actually supplanting the community's voice.

Your comparison with bounties doesn't work, because bounties do not affect (directly) the score of a post. By driving more traffic to a question both question and answers usually receive more up-votes, but a bounty doesn't express the **community's** opinion on the quality of a post, as the score is meant to do.

And beyond this, you are not proposing to allow for multiple down-votes. We already have a problem of users not down-voting often enough, if we allow for multiple up-votes but no multiple down-votes the situation would be even more imbalanced.

Comment: Heh, I'd **love** to have multiple down-votes so that I can feed some of the worst questions to roomba...

Comment: @AndrewT. propose it!

Comment: actually, no, there's no problem with bad ***questions*** not being downvoted enough. it doesn't cost a rep point, as answers, that's why.

Comment: to address your point, we can make the next upvotes progressively more and more costly, like 10,20,50,100 rep points, maybe.

Comment: _"there's no problem with bad questions not being downvoted enough."_ Citation needed. @WillNess

Comment: @Kendra do you want your *secondary sources* with that? :)

Comment: I'm downvoting because lots of non sequiturs. One valid point, ppl with higher rep wd have more power, their opinion wd have more weight (which is debatable whether this is bad or good, actually, but it's a valid point). All the rest is non sequiturs.

Comment: @Will I believe that all the points I brought up are relevant to your proposal. I'm sorry you felt otherwise.

Comment: BTW I very much ***do*** want the ability to multiple down-vote as well. Case in point: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35027952/why-is-haskell-ghc-so-darn-fast Q, and its top voted A, which are both basically marketing hype/BS. The answer even (towards the end) describes a factor (namely, laziness) as having caused an enormous slowdown, then immediately says it is a major reason for why the language in question is "so darn fast". I'd downvote it more (and the Q) if I could. Of course given the reaction here I'm ***hesitant*** to ask/amend this Q here.

Comment: besides, who gave me those points I want to spend, if not ***the community***? in parliamentary democracy, each faction in parliament ***does*** have the unequal voting weight according to the tally of votes ***it*** received during elections, is it not?

Comment: so you see, if instead of making wild assumptions about me and "what I propose" you'd engaged in discussion, as I was hoping for when I asked here for *discussion* (the tag was later removed by someone), and *asked* me instead of accusing me, I'd remembered about this case sooner and we could have this here discussion when it still mattered. but you and ***the community*** went confrontational on me for some reason. isn't it so much better to have dispassionate discussion ***first***, before reaching your conclusions in advance? cheerio.

Comment: @Will, I make no assumptions about you. I read your proposal, as written; disagreed with it; and presented a counterpoint in an answer. Is what how discussion of feature requests is meant to work. Peace.

Comment: peace, yeah, but you could ask, not say "you this and that" as you did. re "as written", these are not court proceedings.

Comment: @AndrewT. I've edited your wish in, requesting the ability to downvote as well, and it got me 4 more downvotes. Interesting what'd happen if you'd asked for it in a separate question. If you do, could you please ping me here, as I'm not an avid meta follower. :)